# How to make KendoNumericTextBox wrapper to render Required model attribute?

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm in an MVC6 project and trying to add a simple Kendo NumericTextBox widget using provided HtmlHelpers.

My model looks like this:

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public double MyNumber {Get; Set;}
    ....
}
```

My view:

```
...
@(Html.Kendo.NumericTextBoxFor(m=>m.MyNumber)
    ...
)
```

But Input tag generated from this code doesn't include the "required" attribute so client validator doesn't check for completness.

Any ideas on how to get the required validation working in client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and asked Telerik people about this. Their answer is that MVC6 is still in pre-release and changing a lot, so they will wait to production release to check for this issues.

Meanwhile, a workaround would be this:

```
@(Html.Kendo.NumericTextBoxFor(m=>m.MyNumber)
    .HtmlAttributes(new {required="required"})
    ...
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this and it works. Unfortunately I will need to replace all workarounds once Kendo people solves the issue, but meanwhile it's ok.